# Superscript font too small in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007, email-client

Now I have problem with Superscript in Outlook 2007/2010. Has anyone have the magic coding to get register mark or number render font to normal. Currently when I send email from Campaign Monitor to Outlook 2007/2010 the register mark or number render font to small, Other email client render font look ok.

```
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
typesetting industry<sup style="font-size: 8px;line-height: 6px; vertical-align: top;">4</sup>.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found superscript to be very inconsistent across clients and avoid using it. Not so much because of the size itself, but because it messes up the line height within a paragraph of text.

Here are a few workarounds:

- Use an image instead. You can use a linked image or go base64 and embed it.
- Wrap it in a span or font tag with a class. Style that in the head so it doesn't affect Gmail.
- Use an Outlook conditional statement to target Outlook '07/'10'13 specifically.